# I want to run my TestNG suite for multiple browsers using Java code. Is there any way for the same?

Tags: java, xml, selenium, testing, testng

I want to run my TestNG suite for multiple browsers using Java code. Is there any way for the same? 
I know how to do that using testng.xml but because of some reason I want to implement this using Java code.

Comment: Then just add multiple Test Runners in your tesNG.xml file. If any Issue comes just post it with exception here.

Comment: @Sandeep I want to implement it using Java code not using testNG.xml, please suggest how to implement using Java code.

Comment: @Krishnan Mahadevan Could you please give me a clue on this... I read your comments and hoping a solution from your end. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let me copy paste some [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically) here

This is your expected xml:

```
<suite name="TmpSuite" >
    <test name="TmpTest" >
            <classes>
                <class name="test.failures.Child"/>
            <classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

That will be your code:

```
XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
suite.setName("TmpSuite");
XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
test.setName("TmpTest");
List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
classes.add(new XmlClass("test.failures.Child"));
test.setXmlClasses(classes)

List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
suites.add(suite);
TestNG tng = new TestNG();
tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
tng.run();
```